# What is the current procedure to add Hilt dependencies to a Kotlin project?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am trying to set up basic Hilt dependency injection in a new project. This is a brand-new project with no added files.

Android Studio version is Hedgehog (2023.1.1) Patch 2.
I chose New Project >> Phone and Tablet >> "Empty Activity" as the project type.
I left all defaults (API 26, Android 8.0; Kotlin DSL) as-is except the project name.

Other's solutions for the error below apparently worked in the past, but standards have changed. For example, most solutions recommend using kapt, but [kapt has been moved to maintenance mode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html) with a recommendation to use ksp. Yet the KSP API [lists Hilt support as 'in progress'](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html#supported-libraries). Kapt errors are mentioned below.

Existing solutions did not work for me, or I am overlooking something being new to Hilt. For reference, I've completed two full stack apps in Android Studio coded in Kotlin without using Hilt.

Current Gradle project sync error:

> Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android.gradle.plugin:com.google.dagger.hilt.android.gradle.plugin.gradle.plugin:2.48')
> Searched in the following repositories:
> Google
> MavenRepo
> Gradle Central Plugin Repository

On returning this error the IDE points to the Plugins section of the Project level `build.gradle.kts`. Note below that I am using Hilt version 2.48 to reduce possible compatibility conflicts 2.50 may have with other libraries. I have tried 2.40, 2.44, and 2.50 with the same result (aside from the listed version number of course).

Below is the settings.gradle.kts:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Project"
include(":app")
```

Project level build.gradle.kts:

```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.22"
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android.gradle.plugin") version "2.48" apply false
}
```

App level build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    // order is important here
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mydomain.myproject"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.mydomain.myproject"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 136
        versionName = "1.36"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    // Enable Jetpack Compose
    buildFeatures {  compose = true }
    // Set the Compose compiler version
    composeOptions { kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.0" }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    // Jetpack Compose dependencies
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.6.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.6.1")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")

    // Viewmodel dependencies
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")

    // Hilt
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48")

    // For instrumentation tests
    androidTestImplementation  ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.48")
    kaptAndroidTest ("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48")

    // For local unit tests
    testImplementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.48")
    kaptTest ("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

Note: `id("kotlin-kapt")` shows no IDE errors, but all `kapt` references in the dependencies section of this file are flagged as `Unresolved reference`. These were added on instruction from the Hilt Gradle Build Setup.

Other reference materials:
[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/hilt-android/2.48)
[Hilt Gradle Build Setup](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup)

Answer (score 1):

In your project's `build.gradle.kts` you just have wrong plugin id for the `hilt`, replace this:

```
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android.gradle.plugin") version "2.48" apply false
```

With

```
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
```

And everything should work just fine, rest of your code is correct.

Comment: I had to remove kapt { correctErrorTypes true } to finish the compile, but your answer did fix the hilt error. Thanks very much!